# необычное поведение переменных в замыкании

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Имеется такой код. Не могу понять, почему после изменения переменной А, переменная В тоже меняет значение. Я ожидал от В такого же поведения как и от переменной S.

```
<script>
        let a = new Array(1, 2, 3);
        let s = a;
        console.log('Before changes:', a);
        function f() {
            let b = a;
            console.log('Funcall:', b);
        }
        f();
        a = new Array(4, 5, 6);
        console.log('After changes:', a);
        f();
        console.log('!#$%%*&:', s);
    </script>
```

Моя аргументация в следующем. При создании переменной, у нас выделяется память в куче под массив и переменная является у нас указателем на эту область памяти. Когда я пишу "присвоить значение А в S", то S будет указателем на область памяти, что и А. В последствии я меняю значение указателя А, но значение указателя S остается неизменным и всё собственно так как я и ожидаю. Те же манипуляции я делаю с В, но она почему то автоматически меняет свое значение с изменением А.

Comment: Переменная `b` является локальной для вашей функции `f`. Значение этой переменной присваивается каждый раз при вызове функции.

Comment: Точно!)) локальная же

Answer (score 0):

Это нормальное поведение, так как при присвоении массива из одной переменной в другую, они по прежнему связаны ссылками друг на друга.

Почитайте здесь:
https://learn.javascript.ru/object-reference